# Как переставить слова "была возведена и принадлежала... ордену"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> В те суровые времена эта «обезьянья башня» была возведена и
>   принадлежала монашескому ордену августинцев.

Как правильно построить предложение?

Неужели вот так скучно:

*В те суровые времена эта «обезьянья башня» была возведена монашеским орденом августинцев и принадлежала ему.*

Мне не нравится...

---

Даю более полный фрагмент текста.

> ...На тот момент в городе насчитывалось более трёхсот укреплённых
>   дозорных башен. Однако, присмотревшись, и сегодня можно обнаружить,
>   что многие из них существуют, просто **включены** *(другое слово!)* в
>   более поздние постройки или обращены в церковные колокольни. В тяжёлые
>   для Рима времена, когда столица мира была захвачена и разграблена
>   неприятелем не раз, когда находилась эта благословенная земля в полном
>   упадке и числа её жителей едва хватило бы, чтобы заполнить трибуны
>   Большого цирка, город словно ощетинился донжонами. Вокруг них
>   выстраивались высокие стены, которые принимали и укрывали в момент
>   нашествий обнищавших горожан. В те суровые времена эта «обезьянья
>   башня» **была возведена и принадлежала монашескому ордену
>   августинцев** *(так нельзя!)*. А по прошествии веков, в XVI столетии,
>   небольшая цитадель **обращена** *(превращена, перестроена,
>   преобразована?)* состоятельной римской семьей Скапуччи в фамильный
>   палаццо. Именно так и зовётся этот дом – palazzo Scapucci. В
>   четырёхугольной средневековой башне были растесаны окна – в прошлом
>   бойницы – и украшены лепниной в угоду новому, барочному, вкусу.

Курсив - это я с автором общаюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разве "в те суровые времена" возможна была ситуация, при которой монашеский орден возводил башни для других? Зачем упоминать очевидное (принадлежала ему)?

"В те суровые времена башня была возведена орденом августинцев" - логические ударения расставлены неверно. Либо "Башня была возведена орденом августинцев в те суровые времена", либо "Башня была возведена в те суровые времена орденом августинцев"

С учетом контекста предлагаю такой вариант:

В те суровые времена **и** была возведена эта «обезьянья башня». Первоначально она принадлежала монашескому ордену августинцев, а по прошествии веков, в XVI столетии, небольшая цитадель **была** превращена состоятельной римской семьей Скапуччи в фамильный палаццо.

Комментарий. "Цитадель превращена в палаццо в XVI столетии" - ОКey, но при другом 
порядке слов нужно добавить слово *была*: "В XVI столетии цитадель **была** превращена в палаццо"

По поводу совместимости понятий *башня* и *цитадель*. После некоторых раздумий, я пришел к выводу, что хотя башня сама по себе — не цитадель, но небольшую цитадель с башней в центре иногда называют башней. Поэтому не буду придираться к тому, что об «обезьяньей башне» пишут как о цитадели.

И еще. Как-то неясно, кого и от кого укрывали стены. Я бы уточнил: "... стены, которые принимали и укрывали **героев нашего рассказа** в момент*Ы* нашествий обнищавших горожан."

Comment: Я добавила тексту в дополнение к вопросу. Речь о дозорной башне, «обезьяньей башне», перепрофилированной орденом августинцев.

Comment: Но там написано, что башня была "перепрофилированна" не орденом августинцев, а семьей Скапуччи!

Comment: Да, с "профилем" я обмишулилась... Но полный текст даёт (ли) право на неперестановку слов? Ога, читаю дополнение к ответу.

Comment: И еще: не в "момент нашествий" , а в  "моментЫ нашествий"

Comment: Угу-ога, спасибо. )))

Answer (score 1):

В те времена... принадлежала... ордену... будучи им возведённой.

Comment: Э. ***В те времена... принадлежала... ордену... будучи им ЖЕ И возведённой.*** Нетути у тя слуха фонетического. И - ты чего пятёрки за умные вопросы не ставишь?! Осержуся...

Comment: Рассматривал такой вариант и счёл такое добавление излишним, поскольку при этом ослабляется причинная роль добавления: больше похоже становится на "ими же потом и снесённая". Фонетический слух нужен больше поэтам, ритмичными завываниями маскирующим отсутствие мысли за своими смутными ощущениями :).

Comment: Сашко, ты што это?! Фонетический слух - это "орфоэпический" слух.

Comment: Ну незя ж смысл слуху подчинять, будь он хоть аморфносонический!

Comment: Змий. Знает же, что я деушка тёмная, ей слово "аморфносонический" неведомо...